# Error importing/installing proprietary plugins - Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, macos, eclipse-plugin, installation

I have been trying for two days now to import some (proprietary) plugins through "Install New Software". 
I also tried to install the plugin on Windows (managed to do so) and on Mac OS (failed with the below error) and now I'm trying to import all the plugins from the Windows Eclipse installation to Mac OS.

Some details on my environment :

- Required Eclipse version 3.7 (I can't make the specific plugin run on anything higher than this)
- Windows 7 / Mac OS Yosemite

What I tried and failed with the below errors:

- Install from .jar installer
- import from .p2f (File->Installer->Export / Import)
- import from existing eclipse installation
- copy plugin folder contents from Windows to Mac OS

Any way to manually install the (proprietary) plugin dependency? I'd gladly do so to fix this.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.10.100.201605020204.
Error reading signed content:/var/folders/0w/j9d33fsd0dn1xncjsm6vypjm0000gn/T/signatureFile1000771104122913962.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /var/folders/0w/j9d33fsd0dn1xncjsm6vypjm0000gn/T/signatureFile1000771104122913962.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.draw2d,3.10.100.201605020204.
Error reading signed content:/var/folders/0w/j9d33fsd0dn1xncjsm6vypjm0000gn/T/signatureFile8525447578852796584.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /var/folders/0w/j9d33fsd0dn1xncjsm6vypjm0000gn/T/signatureFile8525447578852796584.jar
Multiple problems occurred while downloading.
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.11.0.201605020204.
Error reading signed content:/var/folders/0w/j9d33fsd0dn1xncjsm6vypjm0000gn/T/signatureFile2832543910186645793.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /var/folders/0w/j9d33fsd0dn1xncjsm6vypjm0000gn/T/signatureFile2832543910186645793.jar
Problems downloading artifact: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.gef,3.11.0.201605020204.
Error reading signed content:/var/folders/0w/j9d33fsd0dn1xncjsm6vypjm0000gn/T/signatureFile3899147127673910466.jar
An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file: /var/folders/0w/j9d33fsd0dn1xncjsm6vypjm0000gn/T/signatureFile3899147127673910466.jar
```

**Edit**
Seems like these are the correct versions of dependencies, I found them online, but I'm stuck at importing them manually.

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_core.feature,3.3.1.v201107190400-7B7DFO5F7RZHOeJ-SxQ1NJ
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.common_ui.feature,3.3.1.v201107190400-7C79FULEdhO_pfuh6nYekfK0TyR2OK
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.feature,1.3.1.v201108102009-7F78FXRFBBoPbXRPcHfz-uy
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_core.feature,3.3.1.v20110729_1216-30FBc8s73553F5Ia2828
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.server_ui.feature,3.3.1.v20110714_1706-7B77FGPAtJceyEUOhPIXVJNjBF39
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_core.feature,3.3.1.v201107190400-7E7EFMWAJun8_t84-MOI-iP7cRb5srz
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature,3.3.1.v201107072200-7O7IFhREMiB5vNoYqf01XHTvUndyz-yx-9kUyXXL
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_core.feature,3.3.1.v201108102009-7C7OFeKF7RZHQNI3R-OuRb
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature,3.3.1.v201108102009-7H7EFZ3DxumTlaI6nheRdHo2p1KaDIL1Uz-S3PL
```

Comment: The build dates on those plugins are all this month, I doubt that they will work with Eclipse 3.7 which is 5 years old.

Comment: Any workarounds for this?

Comment: Possibly related to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378155 which was fixed in Eclipse Juno packages (3.8/4.0)

Answer (score 1):

The feature `org.eclipse.wst.*` belong to **Web Tools**, you should download [version 3.3.x](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/) for Eclipse v3.7.x
**Web Tools** required [EMF/XSD SDK v2.7.x](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/emf/downloads/?project=emf&showAll=1&hlbuild=R201106060949#R201106060949) and [GEF SDK v3.7.x](http://www.eclipse.org/gef/downloads/), so you have to install them too. Base on downloaded files, There are two solution for install them.

A) Steps for install **Traditional Zip Files** or **All-In-One SDK**:

1. Unpack downloaded file to a folder under **$ECLIPSE_HOME/dropins**
2. Restart Eclipse

You can unpack all zips to one folder or different folder. For example: unpack to folder **webtools** and **gef**, the folder structures should be:

```
$ECLIPSE_HOME/
  dropins/
    webtools/
      eclipse/
        features/
        plugins/
    gef/
      eclipse/
        features/
        plugins/
```

B) Steps for install **P2 repositories in zipped format files** or **All-In-One Update Site**:

1. Unpack downloaded file to local disk. (`artifacts.jar` and `content.jar` can found in the root folder)
2. In Eclipse, select menu item `Help > Install New Software...` Click `Add...` button and `Local...` button to select the folder in previous steps.
3. Click Next button, accept the license agreement until the installation finished.

Note: The download link of EMF/XSD SDK v2.7.1 is invalid. If the (proprietary) plugins work on Eclipse v3.7.2, I suggest you install this version.

Comment: i'll come back to you on Monday, after I test this. Thanks for the answer!